# Doubly Linked List C - stack around variable 'list' was corrupted

Tags: c, structure, doubly-linked-list, stack-corruption

I'm writing a code that splits a doubly linked list `list` into two lists `listA` and `listB` and prints them out. Code seems to get job done but in the end program crashes. Debugger throws
`Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'listA' was corrupted.` and `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'list' was corrupted.` I've read this might be caused by not enough memory allocated for my structure, but how much should I allocate?

Whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* next;
}Node;
typedef struct list {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
}List;

void init(List* l) {
    l->head = NULL;
    l->tail = NULL;
}
Node* create(int val) {
    Node* ptr = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    ptr->val = val;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    ptr->prev = NULL;

    return ptr;
}
void printList(const List* list) {

    Node *ptr = list->head;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%i ", ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    puts("");
    free(ptr);
}
void pushLast(List* l, Node* node) {

    if (l->head == NULL) {
        l->head = node;
        l->tail = node;
    }
    else {
        node->prev = l->tail;
        l->tail->next = node;
        l->tail = node;
    }
}
void splitList(const List* list) {

    List* listA;
    List* listB;
    init(&listA);
    init(&listB);

    Node* ptr = list->head;
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr != NULL) {

        Node* node = create(ptr->val);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            pushLast(&listA, node);
        else
            pushLast(&listB, node);
        i++;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    puts("Input list");
    printList(list);
    puts("Odd nodes list:");
    printList(&listA);
    puts("Even nodes list:");
    printList(&listB);
}

int main(void) {

    List* list;
    init(&list);

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        Node* node = create(i);
        pushLast(&list, node);
    }
    splitList(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

Output received:

```
Input list:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Odd nodes list:
1 3 5 7 9
Even nodes list:
2 4 6 8 10
```

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Does that even compile? You should get an error calling `init`, and all the other functions too.

Comment: `List *listA; init(&listA);` --> `List listA; init(&listA);`  and Other also change in the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not allocating memory for pointers `list`, `listA`, and `listB` to point to.

Second, you are defining `list`, `listA`, and `listB` as `List *`. Then passing `&list`, `&listA`, `&listB` - which are of type `List **` - to your functions, whereas your functions are expecting `List *`.

You need to make below changes in `splitList()`. (Shown only relevant part of code which has errors - or need addition of malloc):

```
void splitList(const List* list) 
{
    List *listA;
    List *listB;

    /* Allocate memory to which these pointers will point */
    if ((listA = malloc(sizeof(List))) == NULL) {
         /* Error handling code */
         exit(1);
    }
    if ((listB = malloc(sizeof(List))) == NULL) {
         /* Error handling code */
         exit(1);
    }

    /* ... */
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
            Node* node = create(ptr->val);
            if (i % 2  ==  0)  
                    /* pushLast(&listA, node); */  /* ISSUE here */
                    pushLast(listA, node);
            else
                    /* pushLast(&listB, node); */  /* ISSUE here */
                    pushLast(listB, node);
            i++;
            ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    /* ... */

    puts("Odd nodes list:");
    /* printList(&listA); */  /* ISSUE here */
    printList(listA);
    free(ListA);  /* Free 1 */
    puts("Even nodes list:");
    /* printList(&listB); */  /* ISSUE here */
    printList(listB);
    free(ListB);  /* Free 2 */
}
```

Also, you need to make similar changes in main:

```
int main(void)
{
    List* list;

    /* Allocate memory */
    if((list = malloc(sizeof(List))) == NULL) {
        /* Error handling code */
        exit(1);
    }

    /* init(&list); */  /* ISSUE here */
    init(list);

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
            Node* node = create(i);
            /* pushLast(&list, node); */  /* ISSUE here */
            pushLast(list, node);
    }
    /* splitList(&list); */   /* ISSUE here*/
    splitList(list);
    free(list); /* free 3 */

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that you need to properly `free` all the memory allocated using `malloc` to avoid memory leak. It can be seen that you are **NOT** freeing all the nodes in. All the you have `free`d is just `one` node in `printList()` function.